Crazyhouse OTB - Promotion
When you promote in Crazyhouse Chess and the promoted piece is captured, the opponent gets a pawn and not whatever piece it was promoted to.
How can you remember in OTB Crazyhouse which promoted pieces were pawns? Any ideas?

This is not a discussion site

It mainly depends on how you drop pieces. If you're using pieces from the same chess board then it's total chaos. If you're using pieces from a different set then you can simply count the number of captured pieces; e.g., both sides lost a queen, then white promotes a pawn to queen, and black captures it. It's quite clear that the queen was promoted since there's also another captured white queen lying on the table. For bishops, rooks, and knights, you can do the same: simply count the number of captured pieces.

If you're using pieces from the same chess set, then it's gonna be quite a headache. You might choose not to drop that piece since it takes up too much time figuring out.
